# How do I know if my Perl module is included under -M?

Tags: perl

Is there anyway to tell from inside a module's `import {}`

```
perl -MFoo -e1
```

apart from

```
perl -e'use Foo;'
```

and, likewise

```
perl -e'package main; use Foo;'
```

I'm trying to have two distinct behaviors for these two. In the `-MFoo` syntax, I want the behavoir of [`oose.pm`](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Moose/lib/oose.pm), but I don't want to have `import` called in the `main` namespace. In the other syntaxes, I want the sub import to happily occur.

Comment: What does the call stack look like in each of these cases?

Comment: That's it, the top is line 0, the bottom is line 1, make it an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the call stack different in each of those cases? It might be as simple at peeking at `caller(0)`.

Looks like the 'line' component is different, at least between cases #1 and #2:

```
package Foo;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
sub import
{
    print Dumper([caller(0)]);
}
1;

# perl -MFoo -e1
$VAR1 = [
          'main',
          '-e',
          0,
          'Foo::import',
          1,
          0,
          undef,
          undef,
          0,
          ''
        ];

# perl -e'use Foo'
$VAR1 = [
          'main',
          '-e',
          1,
          'Foo::import',
          1,
          0,
          undef,
          undef,
          0,
          ''
        ];

# perl -e'package main; use Foo;'
$VAR1 = [
          'main',
          '-e',
          1,
          'Foo::import',
          1,
          0,
          undef,
          undef,
          0,
          ''
        ];
```